# Block transition between minimum value and maximum value in NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am working on an Android application. Somewhere inside, I am displaying the `NumberPicker` widget.

How can I disable the transition between the minimum value and the maximum value?

What I mean, I am using a number picker, with a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 9999. It looks like this,

[image: number picker]

In this way, the user can quickly fling the widget to jump from 0 to 9999.
I do not want this behavior. The number picker widget as it is now looks like a closed circle, and I am trying to see how I can break the circle exactly between the minimum and maximum value, so that it looks like this from the minimum value and maximum value:

[image: number picker minimum value]
[image: number picker maximum value]

How can I achieve this?

What I have tried :

- I searched everywhere in the `NumberPicker` API, it doesn't seem like this is something that one can simply set using a method.
- I think that I can use the method `setDisplayedValues(String[] displayedValues)` method to add empty strings before the minimum value and after the maximum value, so that no value is displayed before the minimum value or after the maximum value, **BUT** the user will still be able to fling past them or WORSE: select the empty value.

Any ideas? Will I have to get my hands dirty and dig in the widget implementation? Inside the touch listener maybe?

Answer (score 13):

You have to call `setWrapSelectorWheel(false)` on the number picker. Be careful though that you do `setMinimumValue(...)` and `setMaximumValue(...)` *before* the call to `setWrapSelectorWheel(false)`. It simply won't work if you do otherwise.

Like me, you may be looking for a way to do this via xml, but there is no way at the time.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this `setWrapSelectorWheel(false)` ([from the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setWrapSelectorWheel%28boolean%29))?

Comment: What's wrong with it? If you set it to `false` you can't go from the minimum to the maximum value or vice versa.

Comment: This is the solution, just make sure that the set setWrapSelectorWheel(false) method is called AFTER initialising the picker values.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, setWrapSelectorWheel(false) does the trick, so one of the offered answers should be accepted.

In general, this order of calls work:

```
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(stringValuesArray.length - 1);
picker.setDisplayedValues(stringValuesArray);
picker.setValue(defaultValue);
picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
```